# .htaccess redirection in php

Tags: .htaccess

I have an image in my `index.php` page.On clicking the image I have to redirect the `URL` to `another Domain` using `.htaccess` redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**HTML CODE**

```
    <a href="http://yourdomain.com/img.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="foldername/img.jpg" alt="image" height="10px" width="25px">
     </a>
```

**.HTACCESS CODE**

```
RewriteRule ^img.jpg$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```